# Open images in a new page and print when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Here is my page: http://budclarychevy.com/custom/parts-specials-test

My aim is to have the images clickable and open in a new window with a prompt to print. The closest method I can find is the `window.print()` function in JavaScript but that just prints the entire page. I'd like each image to open on a printable page by itself. Is this possible with JavaScript? If there's another method, what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can simply add an onclick event with some javascript.

```
<img src="http://budclarychevy.com/path/to/my/image.png"
width="660" height="225" alt="GM Oil Filters"
onclick="newWindow = window.open('http://budclarychevy.com/path/to/img.png');
    newWindow.print();">
```

As you can see, on a click a new window is opened with the url of the picture. As you have a reference to the new window object, you can call the 'print()' function on it.

Cheers
Laidback

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't figure out how to get the new window to bring up the print dialog but I'm okay with that. JavaScript is entirely foreign to me... I've got some studying to do.

Comment: On second thought, it worked perfectly! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
function clicked(address) {

    popup = window.open(); // display popup
    popup.document.write(address.src); // This is where the image url goes which will just open up the image
    popup.print(); // then print the image

}
```

in HTML

```
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="clicked(this)" />
```